# having trouble picking the right formal parameter for a boolean method

Tags: java, variables, methods, boolean

Under the comment version 4, i am trying to create a method named equals that will test the hours, minutes, and seconds. The formal parameter is used again in the return statement. I know i should have it in the  ______.hours format, hours being the instance variable used to test and produce the true or false, but i don't know what should go before the period as the formal parameter. Any suggestions/explanations would be appreciated greatly.

```
public class Clock
{
private static final byte DEFAULT_HOUR =  0,
                        DEFAULT_MIN  =  0,
                        DEFAULT_SEC  =  0,
                        MAX_HOURS    = 24,
                        MAX_MINUTES  = 60,
                        MAX_SECONDS  = 60;

  // ------------------
  // Instance variables
  // ------------------

 private byte seconds,
              minutes,
              hours; 

  public Clock (byte hours  , byte minutes  ,   byte seconds  )
  {
     setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
  }

public Clock (    )
  {
    setTime(DEFAULT_HOUR, DEFAULT_MIN, DEFAULT_SEC);
  }

public void setTime (  byte hours, byte minutes, byte seconds  )
{
this.hours = hours;
this.minutes = minutes;
this.seconds = seconds;
// hours
if (DEFAULT_HOUR >= 0 && DEFAULT_HOUR <= 29)
{

} 

else 
{
  hours = DEFAULT_HOUR;
}
// minutes
if (DEFAULT_MIN >= 0 && DEFAULT_MIN <= 59)
{

} 

else 
{
  minutes = DEFAULT_MIN;
}
// seconds
if (DEFAULT_SEC >= 0 && DEFAULT_SEC <= 59)
{

} 

else 
{
  seconds = DEFAULT_SEC;
}


}
//--------------------------
// Version 3 mutator methods
//--------------------------
public void incrementSeconds()
{
 seconds += 1;
 if (seconds >= 59)
 {
   seconds = DEFAULT_SEC;
   incrementMinutes();
 }

}

public void incrementMinutes()
{
 minutes += 1;
 if (minutes >= 59)
 {
   minutes = DEFAULT_MIN;
   incrementHours();
 }   
}

public void incrementHours()
{
  hours += 1;
  if (hours >= 23)
  {
    hours = DEFAULT_HOUR;
  }
}  

//----------
// Version 4
//----------

public boolean equals(Clock  your_clock)
{
  return  boolean your_clock.hours;
}



//----------
// Version 2
//----------

  public String toString()

  {


    final byte MIN_2DIGITS = 10;

    String str = "";



       // my input

       if (hours < MIN_2DIGITS)
       {
         str += "0" + hours + ":" ;
       }
       else 
         str += hours + ":";
       if (minutes < MIN_2DIGITS)
       {
         str += "0" + minutes + ":" ;
       }
       else
         str += minutes + ":";
       if (seconds < MIN_2DIGITS)
       {
         str += "0" + seconds;
       }
       else
       str += seconds;



     //end of my input 

     return str;

   }


}  // End of class definition
```

Comment: What about `return this.hours == your_clock.hours && this.minutes == your_clock.minutes && this.seconds == your_clock.seconds`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to find equality between the parameter Clock and the caller Clock, I would do the following

```
public boolean equals(Clock another_clock) {
    // Check if 'this' is equal to 'another_clock'

    // 1. If you're checking if the pointer is the same
    return another_clock.equals(this);

    // 2. If you're checking if time is the same (You probably need to create getter/setter methods or change privacy for these fields)
    return another_clock.hours == this.hours &&
        another_clock.minutes == this.minutes &&
        another_clock.seconds == this.seconds;
}
```

Or something along those lines.